# Convert a GET variable containing numbers range to string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, variables

I have a get variable in this format : `0-1499`. Now I need to convert it to a string so that I can explode the variable. For this I tried to convert it to string , but I am not getting any output. Here is the sample code :

```
$mystring = $_GET['myvars']; //equals to 0-1499;
//$mystring = (string)$mystring;
$mystring = strval($mystring);
$mystring = explode("-",$mystring);
print_r($mystring);
```

The above `print_r()` shows an array `Array ( [0] => [1] => 1499 )`. That means it calculates the `$mystring` before converted into string. How can I send `0-1499` as whole string to `explode` ?

Comment: I'm assuming the code above would normally have a `$_GET[]` somewhere in it. Could you possibly edit the code to include this?

Comment: Now replace all of this code with: var_dump($_GET['myvars']); and tell us what the output is.

Comment: the function of explode is to split a string on a character so your code is working as expected (it is splitting the string in half on the '-'). If you want the whole string just remove the explode line.

What results would you like to get from the print_r?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a get variable in this format : 0-1499

When you grab this variable from the URL say.. `http://someurl.com/id=0-1499`

```
$var = $_GET['id'];
```

This will be eventually converted to a string and you don't need to worry about it.

### Illustration

[image]

**`FYI : The above illustration used the code which you provided in the question. I didn't code anything extra.`**

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes, sir.

Should work fine like this.

```
$mystring = "0-1499";
$mystring = explode("-",$mystring);
print_r($mystring);
```

Without the quotes it was numbers / math.

0 minus 1499 = negative 1499

Comment: I believe he replaced a `$_GET[]` value with 0-1499 as if 0-1499 was in the URL request.

Comment: @Josh You are right,`$mystring` is a `GET` variable @Lenny I cant add `""` to it

Comment: Then you aren't getting anything in your get val. Do the following...

var_dump($_GET) and see what you get.

Comment: What is the $_GET line.. maybe that's where the error is? The code I posted above should work as-is it's very simple code so I'm confident that the error is in your input.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly note it treats the value as arithmetic and ignores the `0-` part. If you know that the value you'll get is `0-n` for some `n`, all you need to do is this:

```
$mystring="0-".$n;
$mystring=explode("0-", $mystring);
```

but `explode` here is a bit redundant. So,

```
$myarr=array();
$myarr[1]=strval($mystring);
$myarr[0]="0";
```

There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Explode is used for strings.http://php.net/explode

```
<?php
$mystring = "0-1499";
$a=explode("-",$mystring);
echo $a[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $a[1];

?>
```

see it working here http://3v4l.org/DEstD

Comment: `$mystring = 0-1499` not `"0-1499"`

Comment: @Nitish you can only use explode in case of string ,so in any way u need to convert your input to string.